# NSScrollView height by screen size height

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsscrollview

I'm trying to dynamically adjust the height to the height of the window.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear{
    [super viewDidAppear];
    NSRect size = NSMakeRect([[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.width - WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height);
    [self.view.window setFrame:size display:true];
    [self.collectionScrollView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height)];
```

Compiles everything without a problem, but the height will not change and NSScrollView such as adjusted by the size inspector.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. First, are you using AutoLayout? Second mainScreen is probably not useful. You want view.window.screen but it won't help if you overlap screens. That's just to get started.

Comment: Yes I am using AutoLayout. [self.view.window setFrame:size display:true]; works fine. It set window height by screen resolution. I have a problem with [self.collectionScrollView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame].size.height)]; I try set size manualy by [self.collectionScrollView setFrameSize:NSMakeSize(300,1000) with no effect.

Comment: So the problem is never set a frame when a view is using auto layout.